# How to add column of List<String> and List<Object> to the Room Database?

Tags: android-sqlite, android-room

I am trying to add two more columns to my existing room database:

```
execSQL("ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN cars List<Car>") // -> var cars: List<Car> = listOf()
execSQL("ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN fuel List<String>") //  var fuel: List<String> = listOf()
```

I know how to deal with `String` and `Integer`, but not with a `List<*>`. I searched for and unfortunately, could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to utilise a different table(s) (the correct way database wise) or utilise Type Converters for the Lists of values.

Room can, as you appear to have found, only store a distinct set of types:-

1. String types as a TEXT.
2. Integer types, such a Int, Long, Byte, Boolean .... as INTEGER.
3. Decimal types, such as Double, Float ... as REAL.
4. ByteStream types such as ByteArray .... as BLOB.
5. and nulls as NULL (only if there is no NOT NULL constraint) so not a type that you specify directly.

Any other Type aka Object not directly supported has to be converted to and from one of the 4 Types. Hence per a directly unsupported type 2 TypeConverters will be needed. 1 to convert the object into a value that is a type that can be stored and another to convert from the value to the object when extract the data from the database.

Both Type Converters will be functions and must be annotated with the `@TypeConverter` annotation (NOTE SINGULAR).

The Type Converter that is used to store the converted value would be passed the Object and return the value.

The Type Converter that is used to extract the object would be passed  the value and return the object.

The Class(es) that contain the `@TypeConverter` annotated functions (the Type Converters) needs to be defined to Room via the `@TypeConverters` (**PLURAL**) annotation, which has scope. It is probably best/simplest to include this annotation at the `@Database` annotation level.

You may wish to [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77138228/how-to-create-a-type-converter-for-the-simplest-of-custom-data-class/77138437#77138437), which includes a simple example of a basic type converter.

However,  it is suggested that you consider additional related tables as very often storing lists as a whole becomes complicated largely due to the need to store not only the data but the bloat associated with describing the contents of the stored object.

**Tables instead of Lists**

Loosely based upon this and your previous post. Consider a database where a Car in the databases has a fuel type (Petrol, Diesel ....) and only a single fuel type. **But** that perhaps over time new fuel types may need to be accommodated. So a one to many relationship (a car can have only 1 fuel type but a single fuel type can be used by many cars).

So there would be 2 tables one for cars the other for fuel types.

However, the database, for example, is actually for Car Yards and a Car yard has a list of cars. To further demonstrate and to introduce a many-many relationship that even though unlikely a car yard can have the same car that another car yard has.

Then obviously there would be a table to represent the Car Yards, say an Inventory. To represent a many-many relationship you have an intermediate table that maps (cross references/associates/relates) cars to yards (or yards to cars).

Such a mapping/association/relationship table has 2 columns one for a value that uniquely identifies the car, the other for a value that uniquely  identifies the account/inventory holder. Both columns combined are used together and would form the primary key (a composite primary key). As such any combination of yard and car can be stored (but not the same car and yard more then once).

With the above then the 4 tables could, for example, be represented by the 4 `@Entity` annotated classes:-

```
@Entity(
    indices = [Index(value = ["fuelName"], unique = true)]
)
data class Fuel(
    @PrimaryKey
    var fuelId: Long?=null,
    var fuelName: String
)
@Entity(
    /* Optional. Enforces referential Integrity */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(Fuel::class, parentColumns = ["fuelId"], childColumns = ["fuelTypeMap"],
            /* Optional. Helps maintain referential integrity */
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
    ]
)
data class Car(
    @PrimaryKey
    var carId: Long?=null,
    var manufacturer: String,
    var model: String,
    var timestamp: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    var fuelTypeMap: Long
    /* .... */
)
@Entity
data class Inventory(
    @PrimaryKey
    var accountId: Long?=null,
    var accountName: String
)

/* Many to Many relationship (probably not required as 1 to Many would probably suffice)*/
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["accountIdMap","carIdMap"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(Inventory::class, parentColumns = ["accountId"], childColumns = ["accountIdMap"], onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        ForeignKey(Car::class, parentColumns = ["carId"], childColumns = ["carIdMap"], onDelete =  ForeignKey.CASCADE, onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
    ]
)
data class InventoryCarMap(
    var accountIdMap: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    var carIdMap: Long
)
```

Typically you want to be able to extract a Car with it's fuel type, so a POJO that uses the `@Embedded` annotation to get the Car and uses the `@Relation` annotation to tell Room how to get the respective Fuel. So:-

```
data class CarWithFuel(
    @Embedded
    var car: Car,
    @Relation( entity = Fuel::class, parentColumn = "carId", entityColumn = "fuelId")
    var fuel: Fuel
)
```

There would also very likely be a need to get inventories (yards) and the list of cars they have. Again a POJO with the Inventory `@Embedded`. To get the Cars, then the mapping table needs to be used  as an intermediary table (Junction). The `@Relation` annotation handles this by utilising and expanded set of parameters that define the table. So the POJO is a little more complicated such as:-

```
data class InventoryWithCarsWithFuel(
    @Embedded
    var inventory: Inventory,
    @Relation( entity =  Car::class, parentColumn = "accountId", entityColumn = "carId",
        associateBy = Junction(InventoryCarMap::class, parentColumn = "accountIdMap", entityColumn = "carIdMap"))
    var carList: List<CarWithFuel>
)
```

- Note that Car is the entity (the table from which the data is extracted) and that the mapping table's is solely for the determination of the car, it's values are otherwise not very useful.
- also note that a List is used. Room will know how to get the fuel for the car and do so.

To demonstrate the above an `@Dao` interface as per:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(fuel: Fuel): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(car: Car): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(inventory: Inventory): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(inventoryCarMap: InventoryCarMap): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM inventory")
    fun getAllInventoriesWithCarsEtc(): List<InventoryWithCarsWithFuel>
}
```

- i.e. the ability to insert data into all 4 tables and to extract all the inventories with the cars and with the fuel for the car.

To demonstrate consider the following activity code (`@Database` not included and is pretty standard, although for brevity/convenience `.allowMainThreadQueries` is used for the databaseBuilder):-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: CarDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = CarDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        val f1Id = dao.insert(Fuel(null,"Petrol"))
        val f2Id = dao.insert(Fuel(null,"Diesel"))
        val f3Id = dao.insert(Fuel(null,"LPG"))
        val f4Id = dao.insert(Fuel(fuelName = "Battery"))
        val f5Id = dao.insert(Fuel(fuelName = "Hybrid"))

        val c1Id = dao.insert(Car(manufacturer = "Mazda", model = "CX3", timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000, fuelTypeMap = f3Id))
        val c2Id = dao.insert(Car(manufacturer = "Kia", model = "Rio", timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000, fuelTypeMap = f1Id))
        val c3Id = dao.insert(Car(manufacturer = "Ford",model = "Mustang", timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000, fuelTypeMap = f5Id))
        val c4Id = dao.insert(Car(manufacturer = "Nissan", model = "Leaf", timestamp = 0, fuelTypeMap = f4Id))

        val i1Id = dao.insert(Inventory(accountName = "Fred's CarYard"))
        val i2Id = dao.insert(Inventory(accountName = "Janes Yard of Cars"))

        dao.insert(InventoryCarMap(i1Id,c4Id))
        dao.insert(InventoryCarMap(i1Id,c2Id))
        dao.insert(InventoryCarMap(i1Id,c3Id))
        dao.insert(InventoryCarMap(i2Id,c1Id))
        dao.insert(InventoryCarMap(i2Id,c4Id))

        for (a in dao.getAllInventoriesWithCarsEtc()) {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            for (c in a.carList) {
                sb.append("\n\tCar is ${c.car.manufacturer} ${c.car.model} fuelType is ${c.fuel.fuelName} ....")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","Account is ${a.inventory.accountName}. There are ${a.carList.size} cars. They are:-${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

When run (only intended to be run the once) then the Log is:-

```
2023-09-25 08:08:10.756 D/DBINFO: Account is Fred's CarYard. There are 3 cars. They are:-
        Car is Kia Rio fuelType is Diesel ....
        Car is Ford Mustang fuelType is LPG ....
        Car is Nissan Leaf fuelType is Battery ....
2023-09-25 08:08:10.756 D/DBINFO: Account is Janes Yard of Cars. There are 2 cars. They are:-
        Car is Mazda CX3 fuelType is Petrol ....
        Car is Nissan Leaf fuelType is Battery ....
```

- the Nissan Leaf belonging to both Fred's and Jane's yard is unlikely in real life but has been used to demonstrate the many-many relationship (a more complicated list but one that reduces data redundancy, and therefore the database is more "normalised")

---

### **TypeConverter Demo**

Now consider the following "Aternative" Car entity:-

```
@Entity
data class AltCar(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long?=null,
    var fuelTypeList: List<Fuel>
)
```

Where instead of a single related fuel a list of Fuel objects is to be stored as part of the car (AltCar).

As explained 2 type converters in a class or classes are required, so  :-

```
class TheRoomTypeConverters {
    private val separator1 = "~~"
    private val separator2 = "^^"
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromFuelListToString(fuelList: List<Fuel>) : String {
        val rv = StringBuilder()
        for (fuel in fuelList) {
            if (rv.length > 1) rv.append(separator1) /* separate each Fuel */
            rv.append(fuel.fuelId).append(separator2).append(fuel.fuelName)
        }
        return rv.toString()
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toFuelListFromString(value: String): List<Fuel> {
        val rv = arrayListOf<Fuel>()
        val listOfFuels = value.split(separator1)
        for (f in listOfFuels) {
            val fuelIdAndName = f.split(separator2)
            rv.add(Fuel(fuelId = fuelIdAndName.get(0).toLongOrNull(), fuelName = fuelIdAndName.get(1)))
        }
        return  rv
    }
}
```

- the TypeConverters are deliberately written to give an indication of how the data is being converted (typically a Gson libraray would be utilised to build or extract from a JSON String representation of the objects). They would likely not be TypeConverters used.

To define the TyepConverter class to Room, then:-

```
@TypeConverters(TheRoomTypeConverters::class)
@Database(entities = [Fuel::class, Car::class, Inventory::class, InventoryCarMap::class, AltCar::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
```

- the scope at the @Database level is the greatest, hence it's use (before or after @Database doesn't matter).

Finally some Activity code:-

```
    dao.insert(AltCar(fuelTypeList = listOf(Fuel(999,"Water"),
        Fuel(998,"Hydrogen"), Fuel
    (997,"Plutonium")
    )))
    dao.insert(AltCar(fuelTypeList = listOf(Fuel(999,"Uranium"),Fuel(996,fuelName = "Hydrogen"),Fuel(995,fuelName = "Waste Paper"),Fuel(994,fuelName = "Elbow Grease"))))
    dao.insert(AltCar(fuelTypeList = listOf(Fuel(999,"Paper Waste"),Fuel(993,fuelName = "Hydrogen"),Fuel(992,fuelName = "Waste Paper"),Fuel(991,fuelName = "Elbow Grease"))))

    for (ac in dao.getAllAltCars()) {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for(f in ac.fuelTypeList) {
            sb.append("\n\tFuel is ${f.fuelName}")
        }
        Log.d("INFODB","Car ID is ${ac.id} it has ${ac.fuelTypeList.size} Fuels. They are ${sb}")
    }
```

- as can be seen it's a bit of a mess e.g. Paper Waster or Waste Paper, Waste Paper itself appear twice (the id is irrelevant but to simplify matters the Fuel object was not modified, also the more complicated 2 fields rather than 1 is more encompassing).

When run then the log shows:-

```
2023-09-25 13:05:51.606 D/INFODB: Car ID is 1 it has 3 Fuels. They are 
        Fuel is Water
        Fuel is Hydrogen
        Fuel is Plutonium
2023-09-25 13:05:51.607 D/INFODB: Car ID is 2 it has 4 Fuels. They are 
        Fuel is Uranium
        Fuel is Hydrogen
        Fuel is Waste Paper
        Fuel is Elbow Grease
2023-09-25 13:05:51.607 D/INFODB: Car ID is 3 it has 4 Fuels. They are 
        Fuel is Paper Waste
        Fuel is Hydrogen
        Fuel is Waste Paper
        Fuel is Elbow Grease
```

i.e. the end result is very similar between both techniques.

However inspection of the database via App Inspection is somewhat different:-

The Car table with the relationship to the Fuel looks like:-

[image]

- where the Fuel is mapped by the id of the Fuel, the same Fuel having the same id (not that any have the same type, but they could)

Whilst AltCar with all the Fuels per Car (as an example rather than intending to reflect reality)looks like:-

[image]

As you can see, say for Hydrogen the full word is replicated and thus  at least 8 bytes storage is consumed for each occurrence/use of Hydrogen. Of course then there is the bloat due to the need to separate the values and of course the overheads of separating the values. Whilst SQLite will store a number in as few bytes as is needed so 1...255 will consume 1 single byte for an occurrence up to a maximum of 8 bytes when there are millions or even billions of Fuel  id's. The actual text being stored just the once and thus "normalised".

Imaging trying to do a search for Hydrogen say if Hydrogen Peroxide too were a fuel? No problem with related data, get the id and search on that as the id is unique.

Hence some reasons why, from a database perspective, Lists are better of being another table. It's perhaps more work to setup but in-time it may well save hours of head scratching.